# jQuery mobile and href links inside a table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery mobile and populating a table by using ajax, one of the fields is a href that I'm assigning a class to, to present an alert in the screen, and it does not fire anything:

I have tried by using the double quotes and single quotes without success:

Double quotes:

```
$("#table1").append("<tr><td><a href='#' class='linkTest'>" + element.field1 + "</a></td><td>" + element.field2 + "</td><td>" + element.field3 + "</td></tr>");
```

Single quotes:

```
$("#table1").append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="linkTest">' + element.field1 + '</a></td><td>' + element.field2 + '</td><td>' + element.field3 + '</td></tr>');
```

jQuery method:

```
$(".linkTest").click(function(){
    alert("It works");
});
```

The table is populated correctly but the alert is not showing up when clicked. If I add a button outside the table, it works:

```
<a href="#" class="linkTest"> TEST </a>
```

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: You can bind the click to the document so its always listening. and you dont need to include href="#" -- https://jsfiddle.net/o04pescz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your link is dynamically added to DOM, so click event will not work.

> This is exactly what you looking for [**event Delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and
>   also have to prevent default function of hyperlink

Consider following snippet:

```
$("#table1").on('click','.linkTest', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//for prevent default redirect
    alert("It works");
});
```

Comment: It works! thanks! Maybe I have to create another thread for this, but, is there a way to get the <td> value and present it in the javascript alert? Thanks!

Comment: I just got it to work by using: **alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());** to display the first column value, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$(".linkTest").click()` won't apply to any dynamically created elements added subsequently. Either do `$(".linkTest").click()` after the dynamic content is added or bind the event to a containing element e.g. `$('body').on('click', '.linkTest', function() { });`